# Plotly Dash: Create dropdown dynamically from binary tree splits

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a binary tree and would like to create a dynamic "decision process", where the next question showing is dependent on the current choice. A mini scenario is following, where each node has a question associated with it and two choices:

From the root node, the first dropdown will have two options B and C. After selecting either B or C, the next dropdown will appear containing either options D/E or F/G depending on their parent node. This goes on until a leaf node is reached and no further dropdown is created.

```
from anytree import Node, RenderTree

A = Node("A")
B = Node("B", parent = A)
C = Node("C", parent = A)

D = Node("D", parent = B)
E = Node("E", parent = B)

F = Node("F", parent = C)
G = Node("G", parent = C)

for pre, fill, node in RenderTree(A):
    print("%s%s" % (pre, node.name))
```

[image]

A function for `options` argument in `dcc.Dropdown`:

```
def FUNC_get_dropdown_options(parent):

values = [subnode.value for subnode in parent.children]
labels = [subnode.label for subnode in parent.children]

dropdownOptions = []
for value, label in zip(values, labels):
    dropdownOptions.append({"label": label, "value": value})
return(dropdownOptions)

--- [Console] ---
In: FUNC_get_dropdown_options(A)
Out: [{'label': 'B', 'value': 'B'}, {'label': 'C', 'value': 'C'}]
```

I wrote this:

```
#%% Layout of app

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

# Dropdown
dropDownContainer = html.Div(id = "dropDownContainer", children = [
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dropDown0',
        options = FUNC_get_dropdown_options("A"),
        placeholder = "Select an option"
    )])

app.layout = html.Div([dropDownContainer, html.Div("outputContainer")])


@app.callback(
    Output("outputContainer", "children"),
    Input("dropDown0", "value"))

def create_new_dropdown(value, children):
    new_dropdown = dcc.Dropdown(
        id={
            'type': 'filter-dropdown',
            'index': value
        },
        options = FUNC_get_dropdown_options(value)
    )
    children.append(new_dropdown)
    return children

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

But it wouldn't work. I still haven't grasped the concept of callbacks that well. Thank you in advance for your help.